How to check a generate code by simply-jwt
I try to verify a code generate by simply-jwt, but the second step when I tried to verify this, it's become False and I try to understand why
the purpose it's to generate a code after login and verify this code in a second step
here the views calls on the url:
class ObtainAuthTokenStep1(TokenViewBase):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']

            # Generate a 2FA code and secret
            secret = base64.b32encode(SECRET_KEY.encode()).decode()
            totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
            verification_code = totp.now()
            send_verification_code_via_email(user, verification_code)

            # Generate a code token with the secret embedded
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            refresh['totp_secret'] = secret
            code_token = str(refresh.access_token)

            response_data = {
                'code_token': code_token,
                'message': 'Verification code sent to your email.'
            }

            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

and the serializers for the check:
class AuthTokenStep2Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    code_token = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        code_token = attrs.get('code_token')
        code = attrs.get('code')

        if code_token and code:
            decode_token(code_token)

            secret = base64.b32encode(SECRET_KEY.encode()).decode()
            totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
            if not totp.verify(code):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid code.'))
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Must include "code_token" and "code".'))

        return attrs

If I do the same thing in a terminal I don't have any problem and the sending code work well

why do you wanna customize JWT like that? If you want to customize JWT see this : https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html
